# how to upload multiple images (from a folder) using c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-gallery

Instead of uploading image one by one, how do i achieve to upload all the images from the folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [flash](http://www.swfupload.org/) or [java](http://jumploader.com/). I like the java one I posted in the link because it is extremely easy. Though the flash one is easier to customize.

Comment: Flash has a 99% client penetration rate whereas Java's is much lower, 56% - 77% depending on which study you read.

Comment: @Sam, very true. That and java takes forever to initialize in the browser. I still like jumploader (java) for its ease of use.

Comment: So David, as you understood my question that i need something so that I can select multiple files together and upload them (not one bye one)... My project is in asp.net using c#. I don't know if i can use Flash or Java in this project.  Can you suggest something related to .net?

Comment: Sorry to say Flash or Java are your only options that I have seen (well, there is Silverlight too). Both the solutions I linked to provide code examples for implementing in asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with HTML alone but you can with a combination of JavaScript and Flash.  Here's a component that you can use.

http://www.swfupload.org/

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to implement this with NeatUpload, in a C#/.Net project.

Answer (score 0):

[SlickUpload - ASP.NET Uploading Made Simple. And Slick.](http://krystalware.com/Products/SlickUpload/)

Requires no client-plugin, provides progress, and also avoids some nasty issues of ASP.Net.

Comment: this doesn't do a multiple file select does it?

Comment: Well, not exactly no.  You pick one file at a time yet they all upload at once after all files have been selected.

Answer (score 0):

Please note: it is not *required* to have Flash or Java to upload multiple files, although using Flash or Java or Silverlight will probably give a better user experience in the long run.

You *can* do it in pure AJAX, but it's very tricky and prone to cross-browser issues. There are controls you can purchase that do the work and are fairly polished; SlickUpload is one, but I prefer [RadUpload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/usingtargetfolder/defaultcs.aspx).

Comment: this doesn't do a multiple file select either.

Comment: @David Murdoch: Sure it does.

Comment: can you link me an example? I couldn't find it.

Comment: All I see is a form to select one file, click add, select another, click add, and repeat.  Not nearly as easy to use as a Flash based uploader.

Comment: Oh, you want multiple file select in a dialog? Well, you'll need better UI than that, as I suggested *in my first sentence*. But it wasn't a **requirement** of the original question, just the ability to upload multiple files, so please feel free to feel really really guilty about your downvote, downvoter.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter...but I do have to say: I think it was a __requirement__ of the original. Otherwise options like [ajaxupload.js ](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) would have be mentioned.   :-)

Comment: @David Murdoch: that's a big assumption, given the size and quality of the original question.

Comment: @Randolpho. David got my question right. And i am sure my question has enough size and quality to explain what I want to explain... 
Anyways I need an answer that can help me. Can you help me?

Comment: @Randolpho, I'm the downvoter and I don't feel guilty at all.  AJAX has not advanced to the point of being able to handle all things well and multi-file upload is certainly one of them.  A Flash based solution is really the best option.  Even Google uses Flash for this.